# Resistance of Light Dependent Resistor (LDR)

Tags: visible-light, semiconductor-physics, electrical-resistance, electrical-engineering

Is there a mathematical expression relating the resistance of [Light Dependent Resistor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoresistor) (LDR) with light intensity?

Comment: Would http://electronics.stackexchange.com be a better home for this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some types it's quite simple.

[image]

From [RS Data sheet for NORP12](http://docs-europe.electrocomponents.com/webdocs/001a/0900766b8001a9d6.pdf)

Note: This is a [log-log plot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-log_plot) of resistance against illuminance (in Lux) not luminous intensity (Candela, cd)